# Deadlock when previous query threw an exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Using entity framework, I have a function that basically goes something like this:

```
using (var ctx = new Dal.MyEntities())
{
    try
    {
        //...
        // create a temp entity
        Dal.Temp temp = new Dal.Temp();
        // populate its children
        // note that temp is set to cascade deletes down to it's children
        temp.Children = from foo in foos
                        select new Dal.Children()
                        {
                            // set some properties...
                            Field1 = foo.field1,
                            Field2 = foo.field2
                        }
        //...
        // add temp row to temp table
        ctx.Temp.Add(temp);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        // some query that joins on the temp table...
        var results = from d in ctx.SomeOtherTable
                      join t in temp.Children
                      on new { d.Field1, d.Field2 } equals new { t.Field1, d.Field2 }
                      select d;
        if (results.Count() == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("no results")
        }
        // Normal processing and return result
        return results;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (temp != null && temp.ID != 0)
        {
            ctx.TempTables.Remove(temp);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    } 
}
```

The idea is that as part of the processing of a request I need to build a temporary table with some data that then gets used to join the main query and filter the results. Once the query has been processed, the temp table should be deleted. I put the deletion part in the `finally` clause so that if there is a problem with the query (an exception thrown), the temporary table will always get cleaned up.

This seems to work fine, except intermittently I have a problem were the `SaveChanges` in the `finally` block throws a deadlock exception with an error message along the lines of:

```
Transaction (Process ID 89) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and 
has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I can't reliably reproduce it, but it seems to happen most often if the *previous* query threw the "no results" exception. Note that, due to an error that was discovered on the front end, two identically requests were being submitted under certain circumstances, but nevertheless, the code should be able to handle that.

Does anybody have an clues as to what might be happening here? Is throwing an exception inside the `using` block a problem? Should I handle that differently?

Update, so the exception might be a red herring. I removed it altogether (instead returning an empty result) and I still have the problem. I've tried a bunch of variations on:

```
using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted })
using (var ctx = new Dal.MyEntities())
{

}
```

But despite what I've read, it doesn't seem to make any difference. I still get intermittent deadlocks on the second `SaveChanges` to remove the temp table.

Comment: Speaking as a database developer, we generally recommend against trying to manually drop temp tables directly for a number of reasons. Presumably, once your `using` is done, your session should close, which means you wouldn't need your `finally`. Have you tried leaving it out altogether?

Comment: @JasonWhitish: I'm not dropping the table, just the row from the table. I need to clean it up so it doesn't just grow out of control (I could, of course, consider setting something else up to periodically purge the table, but that seems a bit hacky). I'm open to other ideas. I need to be able to join the rest of the query with the row(s) in the table (actually tables, but it cascades deletes from the "header") because I need to join on two columns rather than just one.

Comment: You're almost certainly blocking yourself where either the delete is trying to pull rows at the same time you have an exclusive lock on the table (which is why isolation level doesn't help). That's also why "two identically requests were being submitted under certain circumstances" could fail if in the same session. It would help to know for sure. Do you have access to SQL Server Profiler? You can do this if so: http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/gathering-deadlock-information-deadlock-graph

Answer (score 0):

how about adding a

```
using (var ctx = new Dal.MyEntities())
{
    try
    {
        //...
        Dal.TempTable temp = new Dal.TempTable();
        //...
        ctx.TempTables.Add(temp);
        // some query that joins on the temp table...
        if (no
        results are 
        returned)
        {
            throw new Exception("no results") 
        }
        // Normal processing and return result
    }
    catch
    {
        ctx.TempTables.Remove(temp);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (temp != null && temp.ID != 0)
        {
            ctx.TempTables.Remove(temp);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't help. It's just doing the same thing as the `finally` block only now it will attempt to remove the same item twice if an exception is thrown (one in the `catch` and once in the `finally` block).